# How to create column with default and required values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying this code but I'm getting this error message: *An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.*

```
ALTER TABLE customers 
ADD         active int
DEFAULT     (1) 
CONSTRAINT  chk_active
CHECK       (0,1);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining a check constraint you have to actually refer to the column name, i.e. `CHECK (Active IN (0,1)` instead of just `CHECK (0, 1)`. So your syntax would be

```
ALTER TABLE Customers ADD 
    active INT DEFAULT (1)
    CONSTRAINT  chk_active CHECK (Active IN (0,1));
```

It is also probably a good idea to name your default constraint, and include the table name in the constraint name so that you don't conflict with similar constraints on other tables:

```
ALTER TABLE Customers ADD 
    Active INT CONSTRAINT DF_Customers__Active DEFAULT (1)
    CONSTRAINT CHK_Customers__Active CHECK (Active IN (0,1));
```

However, it would seem more appropriate to have a not null bit column so the check constraint is not required:

```
ALTER TABLE Customers ADD Active BIT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Customers__Active DEFAULT(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE customers 
ADD         active int

GO

ALTER TABLE customers 
ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_active ] DEFAULT     (1) FOR active

GO

ALTER TABLE customers 
ADD CONSTRAINT [chk_active] CHECK (active>=0 AND active <=1)
```

I would suggest you do it like this. Also always conside adding a name to your constraint.

As a facut, why don't u use `active` as `bit` column so you won't need the `CHECK` constraint.

Comment: What is the meaning of active>=0 AND active <=0. It look like to accept all int

Comment: @TotaloDotoNeto he wants a check constraint to allow only 1 or 0. I've made a typing mistake, i've edited it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
ALTER TABLE Customers ADD 
active INT DEFAULT (1)
CONSTRAINT  chk_active CHECK (Active IN (0,1));
```